# Ruby string to int/float conversion

Tags: ruby

So let's say I have a string, `'$3,444.11'`. How do I convert that to a float `3,444.11`? I have a form field. The user can insert `"3,444.11"`, `"3444.11"`, or `"$3,444.11`" or `"€3,444.11"`. What I need is `3,444.11` as a float. Will I have to resort to regex? Or, is there a function already that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think there's anything in the standard library that does this for you.  Here's a quick one-liner:

```
'$3,444.11'.gsub(/[^\d\.]/, '').to_f
# => 3444.11
```

However, you might want to take a look at the [`money`](http://rubymoney.github.com/money/) gem for advanced processing of currency strings.